# Can a batter be out stumped on a free hit?

Tags: rules, cricket

On a free hit, suppose the ball hits the bails and dislodges them, then goes to the wicketkeeper's hands.

If they then remove a stump from the ground while the batsman is out of their crease, is this out or not out?

Answer (score 3):

The answer to this is not out.  A batsmen can only be out from a free hit from the methods you can be out from a no ball.  [Law 21 No Ball](https://www.lords.org/mcc/laws-of-cricket/laws/law-21-no-ball/).

This does not include stumped.  Stumped is defined in [Law 39](https://www.lords.org/mcc/laws-of-cricket/laws/law-39-stumped/) and involves the wicket keeper without the actions of another fielder.

Hence the answer of not out.